# How to load data to scope on page load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have to show data when the page is loaded. So to do that how should I load the data into scope.

I could see three possiblities, but my question is which one should I use.Whether one method has any advantage over the others, or all three method is the same?

**Method 1:**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.data = [];

        function loadData() {
            $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response;
            });
        }
        loadData();

    });

}());
```

**Method 2:**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.data = [];

        $scope.init = function () {
            $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response;
            });
        };

    });

}());
```

and bind init() in view.

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
```

**Method 3:**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.data = [];

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response;
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

Is there any other way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: @StefanBaiu version 1.4.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1** - this is the best option. Your load data logic is in its own function so you could easily call it again if you need to re-load your data at any point. Keeps the functionality reusable. You should use the Promise's `then()` and `catch()` methods to handle success and failure.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data = [];

    function loadData() {
        $http.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                $scope.error = error;
            });
    }

    loadData();
});
```

**Method 2** - this should work fine, but the downside is that it's not clear when looking at the controller how `init()` is being called.

**Method 3** - again this should work, but the `angular.element(document).ready()` call is unnecessary and makes your code more confusing. Also the logic for getting data is no longer reusable and in it's own function.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know angular bootstraps on `DOMContentLoaded` so there's no need for `.ready()`.

Also, I find `ng-init` to be redundant, the controller should initialize values for the view.

So I guess the first one is the lucky winner.

Answer (score 1):

1st way is good, but you should 'then' not 'success'. Also usually you can omit initializing your variable.

```
(function () {

    angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
        function loadData() {

            $http.get('q.html').then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
            }, function(error) {
                //handle
            });
        }
        loadData();

    });

}());
```